# Crash on App start iOS version 8.0.8

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

We updated SDK version to 8.0.8 for using InApp messaging by method "trackEvent". Testing didn't catch crashes on app start. But we have a lot of it on production after release. We don't have any idea why it happens. As I can see the crash happens on SDK initialization. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Crash examples
[image]

[image]

or crashes like this:
[image]

Also we have these crash log by Apple Connect logger

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community is it clear now?

Comment: I'm am seeing the same behaviour, App crashes on startup due to SDK initialization. Not same stack trace but same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in the SDK, but a workaround for this would be [implementing a custom logger](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/ios-debugging.html#file-enable_debug_logs_outputter-v8-x-js). A fix is being peer reviewed and tested. Here's an example that should resolve this specific crash for you:

```
class CustomLogOutputter: LogOutputter {
    override func out(level: LogLevel, subsystem: String, category: LoggerCategory, message: String) {
        os_log("Subsystem: %@, LoggerCateogry: %@, Message: %@", subsystem, category.rawValue,message)
    }
}
 
SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug, logOutputter: CustomLogOutputter())
```